# Can't find file trying to move

Tags: perl

I'm trying to clean up a directory that contains a lot of sub directories that actually belong in some of the sub directories, not the main directory.

For example, there is

```
Main directory
     sub1
     sub2
     sub3     
     HHH
```

And HHH belongs in sub3. HHH has multiple text files inside of it (as well as some `..txt` and `...txt` files that I would like to ignore), and each of these text files has a string

```
  some_pattern [sub3].
```

So, I attempted to write a script that looks into the file and then moves it into its corresponding directory

```
use File::Find;

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;

my $DATA = "D:/DATA/DATA_x/*";
my @dirs = grep { -d } glob $DATA;

foreach (@dirs) {

  if ($_ =~ m/HHH/) {
    print "$_\n";
    my $file = "$_/*";
    my @files = grep { -f } glob $file;

    foreach (@files) {
      print "file $_\n";
    }

    foreach (@files) {
      print "\t$_\n";
      my @folders = split('/', $_);

      if ($folders[4] eq '..txt' or $folders[4] eq '...txt') {
        print "$folders[4] ..txt\n";
      }

      foreach (@folders) {
        print "$_\n";
      }

      open(FH, '<', $_);
      my $value;
      while (my $line = <FH>) {
        if ($line =~ m/some_pattern/) {
          ($value) = $line =~ /\[(.+?)\]/;
          ($value) =~ s/\s*$//;
          print "ident'$value'\n";
          my $new_dir = "$folders[0]/$folders[1]/$folders[2]/$value/$folders[3]/$folders[4]";
          print "making $folders[0]/$folders[1]/$folders[2]/$value/$folders[3]\n";
          print "file is $folders[4]\n";
          my $new_over_dir = "$folders[0]/$folders[1]/$value/$folders[2]/$folders[3]";
          mkdir $new_over_dir or die "Can't make it $!";
          print "going to swap\n '$_'\n for\n '$new_dir'\n";
          move($_, $new_dir) or die "Can't $!";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's saying

```
Can't make it No such file or directory at foo.pl line 57, <FH> line 82.
```

Why is it saying that it won't make a file that doesn't exist?

A while later: here is my final script:

```
use File::Find;

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;

my $DATA = "D:/DATA/DATA_x/*";
my @dirs = grep { -d } glob $DATA;

foreach (@dirs) {

  if ($_ =~ m/HHH/) {
    my $value; 
    my @folders;
    print "$_\n";
    my $file = "$_/*";
    my @files = grep { -f } glob $file;

    foreach (@files) {
      print "file $_\n";
    }

    foreach (@files) {
      print "\t$_\n";
      @folders = split('/', $_);

      if ($folders[4] eq '..txt' or $folders[4] eq '...txt') {
        print "$folders[4] ..txt\n";
      }

      foreach (@folders) {
        print "$_\n";
      }

      open(FH, '<', $_);
      while (my $line = <FH>) {
        if ($line =~ m/some_pattern/) {
          ($value) = $line =~ /\[(.+?)\]/;
          ($value) =~ s/\s*$//;
          print "ident'$value'\n";
        }
      }


      }
        if($value){
        print "value $value\n";
        my $dir1 = "/$folders[1]/$folders[2]/$folders[3]/$folders[4]/$folders[5]";
    my $dir2 = "/$folders[1]/$folders[2]/$folders[3]/$folders[4]/$value";
        system("cp -r $dir1 $dir2");
      } 

    }
  }
}
```

This works. It looks like part of my problem from before was that I was trying to run this on a directory in my D: drive--when I moved it to the C: drive, it worked fine without any permissions errors or anything. I did try to implement something with `Path::Tiny`, but this script was so close to being functional (and it was functional in a Unix environment), that I decided to just complete it.

Comment: You should check the `Path::Class` module, what contains a good implemetation of `traverse` or  `recurse` methods, or `Path::Tiny` what contains the `iterator` with a possibility of recursive search. It would be more easy to solve with the already existing well-written modules.

Comment: In order to easily deal with directory and file paths you can also consider to have a look at [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) and [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) modules.

Comment: Could your new directory name be containing invalid characters? (single quotes for example)? Please print dir name on failyre

Comment: When I `chomp` it, I get `Can't make it File exists at fix_directories.pl line 68, <FH> line 82.`

Comment: It doesn't look like it contains invalid characters

Comment: Print the file name using `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $new_over_dir;`

Comment: dumper gives `$VAR1 = "D:/DATA/DATA_x/sub3/HHH";`

Comment: I'm tempted to just write a new script with `File::Find `

Comment: @user2795733 Sometimes it is a good thing to succumb to temptation. This would be one of those times.

Comment: Yes, I switched to Cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **really** should read the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path%3a%3aTiny) doccu. It probably contains everything you need.

Some starting points, without error handling and so on...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

my $start=path('D:/DATA/DATA_x');
my $iter = path($start)->iterator({recurse => 1});

while ( $curr = $iter->() ) {

    #select here the needed files - add more conditions if need
    next if $curr->is_dir;  #skip directories
    next if $curr =~ m/HHH.*\.{2,3}txt$/;   #skip ...?txt

    #say "$curr";
    my $content = $curr->slurp;
    if( $content =~ m/some_pattern/ ) {
        #do something wih the file
        say "doing something with $curr";

        my $newfilename = path("insert what you need here"); #create the needed new path for the file ..
        path($newfilename->dirname)->mkpath; #make directories
        $curr->move($newfilename);           #move the file
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: `$newfilename` is the actual file name (e.g. `'dir1/dir2/file.txt'`)? and `mkpath` will ensure that all of the directories exists before putting `file.txt` in?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure of the directory path you are trying to create. The *mkdir* call might be failing if some of the intermediate directories doesn't exist. If your code is robust to ensure that 
the variable **$new_over_dir** contains the directory path you have to create, you can use method *make_path* from perl module [File::Path](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/File-Path-2.09/Path.pm) to create the new directory, instead of 'mkdir'.

From the documentation of *make_path*:

> The make_path function creates the given directories if they don't
>   exists before, much like the Unix command mkdir -p.

Comment: `make_path` gives me `Can't make it Inappropriate I/O control operation at fix_directories.pl line 59, <FH> line 82.`

Comment: @user2795733 Why not check what is in your `@folder` array by printing it with `Data::Dumper`? `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@folder;`.

Comment: It prints $VAR1 = [
          'D:',
          'DATA',
          'DATA_x',
          'HHH',
          'text_file_inside_HHH'
        ];